# Python is not recognized in Sublime3 even though my path is correct?

Tags: python, path, sublimetext3

If I run the basic IDLE on Python, it will run my scripts but when I try to run them though Sublime 3 it states Python is not recognized. This is even though Python is already added to my path.

Another odd thing is when I type `python` in my command line it is not recognized but if type in `py`, it shows the Python version.

This is the path:

```
[path:C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\NVIDIACorporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\ATITechnologies\ATI.ACE\CoreStatic;C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\;C:\Users\Tommy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts]
```

Comment: Have you created a build system for it?

Answer (score 1):

The `python.exe` file has to be in one of directories listed in the `PATH` variable.

If it's not in

```
C:\Users\Tommy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts
```

then you have to add another directory. My guess would be the `Python37` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Your PATH should also point to

```
C:\Users\Tommy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\
```

it just points to Python's scripts, not Python itself.

Sublime tries to use `"python"`, but as it isn't in PATH, it doesn't work. That is the same for your command line.

If you point it to the folder I used, it will look for Python 3.7, if you need to use other Python's versions, you can use the `py` helper.

For example, for Python 3.6:

```
py -3.6 <script>
```